# Unable to display the age of an object that was passed to a kotlin function

Tags: string, function, kotlin, class, intellij-idea

I'm just starting to learn kotlin and ran into a problem:

***I have a Person class that has two fields***
-*age* (Int data type)
-*name* (data type String)

there is also a ***oldUp*** function where I pass a Person object and increment the object's age field by 10.

Before the end of the program ** I want to display the age of the object that was passed to oldUp **
However, age is not shown.

my code:

```
class Person(var name: String, var age: Int){
}

fun growOld(human: Person){
    human.age+=10
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var human = Person("Kitty",6)
    growOld(human)
    println(human)
}
```

Comment: age of an object can be understood in two ways in programming, I would change it to something like 'property of object'

Comment: @folibis how can i implement it?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the age, you can just write: `println(human.age)`.

In your example it might be cleaner to add the `growOld` method to your class so you can call it on the object. For example:

```
class Person(var name: String, var age: Int){
    fun growOld() {
        this.age += 10
    }
}


fun main() {
    var human = Person("Kitty", 6)
    println(human.age) // prints 6
    human.growOld()
    println(human.age) // prints 16
    println(human.name) // prints Kitty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to *print* the `human` object itself. Under the hood, this calls its `toString()` method - every class has one of these, because it's defined on the type all classes derive from. If you don't override it and provide a nice way to "pretty print" your object, it'll use the default implementation, which is basically a reference to the object in memory.

A lot of classes you use have a nice `toString()` implementation, e.g. if you print a `List` you get `["something", "that", "looks", "like", "this"]`. But that behaviour needed to be coded in - and you need to do that for your `Person` class too!

So you can *override* the default implementation like this:

```
override fun toString(): String {
    // return a String here
}
```

*override* means you're taking an existing function and writing your own version of it to use instead - if this doesn't match an existing function you can override, you'll get an error. You'll also get an error if you *don't* use the `override` keyword for a function that looks exactly like an existing one in a supertype - it's just to make sure you don't accidentally do the wrong thing. In *IntelliJ* you can do *Ctrl+O* to override existing functions if you like.

---

So you could do something like this:

```
// inside your Person class
override fun toString(): String {
    return "Name: $name, age: $age"
}
```

and then when you use it in a `print` statement, or in a string (like `"Details: $person"` or `val details = "Details: " + person`) it will call that `toString()` method and get the string you produced.

---

Another way to approach this is to use a [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html):

```
data class Person(var name: String, var age: Int)
```

A *data class* is a special kind of class where all your "data" goes in the constructor (as properties, either `val` or `var`), and then you get some boilerplate stuff for free which uses those properties (and *only* those properties). Things like an `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementation that uses that data - and the relevant thing here, it gives you a `toString()` implementation that pretty prints `name` and `age`. Try it out!

Data classes can be really handy for simple data objects like you have here - but in normal classes, overriding `toString()` yourself is the general way of doing things. And you can still override a *data class*'s `toString` if you want - sometimes you might want a more complex representation, or nice formatting, or you might want to only include some properties and ignore others. You're in control of how it prints itself!

And if you just want to print the `age` property, or print anything at all using the data in your object, then you just need to do what [Robin's answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74026762/13598222). You don't need a `toString()` implementation at all for that (and since this is how you usually use objects, often you won't need to write a `toString` for your own classes at all)